# I'm a UK citizen, can I use US stockbrokers?

Tags: stocks, trading, broker

I want to invest in global stocks and I like the look of several US based online stock brokers.

Is there a difference using one of these stock brokers instead of a UK based one?

How does a UK based account purchase US stocks and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

The UK has historically aggressive financial law, inherited from Dutch friendship, influence, and acquisitions by conquest.

The law is so open that nearly anyone can invest through the UK without much difficulty, and citizens have nearly no restrictions on where to invest.

A UK citizen can either open an account in the US with paperwork hassles or at home with access to all world markets and less paperwork.  Here is the [UK version](https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/en/main.php?red=1) of my broker, Interactive Brokers.  Their costs are the lowest, but you will be charged a minimum fee if you do not trade enough, and their minimum opening balance can be prohibitively high for some.

If you do buy US products, be sure to file your [W-8BEN](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-W-8BEN,-Certificate-of-Foreign-Status-of-Beneficial-Owner-for-United-States-Tax-Withholding).

Comment: Without `W-8BEN` you will not be able to start. Unless you fill it in, they willn't allow you to trade in US markets.

Comment: `aggressive financial law` is for the protection of consumers. No need to be acerbic. As UK doesn't have a sue for money culture as in US, the government has put in safety measures to protect people. Not only in UK, it is EU wide. EU regulations are more consumer centric than company centric. `The law is so open that nearly anyone can invest through the UK without much difficulty, and citizens have nearly no restrictions on where to invest.`, not any more.

Comment: @DumbCoder The UK after the wave of US credit regulation starting in the mid to late 60s used to be the center of credit & forex trading until the US began deregulating in the 80s.  The US now sees less need to trade through the UK, and tax havens, flush with cash, are becoming more the ultimate source of global credit.  That previous dominance is what made LIBOR the primary interest rate data source, also now waning.

Comment: I see you still haven't learnt anything from your past experiences and still providing tangential arguments. I will stop here, but you can continue doing so.

Comment: @DumbCoder Since my "aggressive financial law" quote had nothing to do with the protection of consumers and everything to do with the UK's history as a trading nation, modeled off the Nederlands, my comment was an attempt to maintain the question & answer's perspective on investment freedom despite a tangential comment offered.  I will stop too.